# Test Cafe Selectors to find following element

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

1) I need to change //input[@name='loc']/parent::div/following::div[3] as Testcafe compatible Sectors. Is there any wrong with below one :

const locate = Selector('input').withAttribute('name','loc').parent('div').sibling('div').nth(3);

or

const locate = Selector('input').withAttribute('name','loc').parent('div').nextSibling('div').nth(3);

2) Do we have any add-in/tool to evaluate TestCafe selectors ( like ChroPath, xpath-finder, etc.)?

const locate = Selector('input').withAttribute('placeholder','loc').parent('div').sibling('div').nth(3);

Answer (score 2):

I would say that best candidate is `const locate = Selector('input').withAttribute('name','loc').parent('div').nextSibling('div').nth(3);`

A simple way to validate a Selector is by using the TestCafe assertion API:

```
await t
  .expect(locate.with({visibilityCheck : true}).exists)
  .ok()
  .hover(locate);
```